# Nibs view in other nibs subview with coreplot, cpgraph takes super view as its attribute

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, core-plot, loadnibnamed

I load a A-viewcontrollers view to other B-viewcntrollers sub view (`UIview`), A is having graphs with `coreplot` and initialize CPTgraph. When 'A' is initialize all the property of it like.:array or labels are being property of cptgraph instance so it is giving me error. 
Can anyone please help me with this. 
Thanks in advance.

error is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString sizeWithTextStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75b1e50'
```

Comment: CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];  here ,'graph' is being 'self' !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a category method added by Core Plot. Make sure your project uses both the -ObjC and -all_load linker flags. See http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications#Dependent_Project_Install for more information.